# Gmail filters don't work if it is set up to both label and then delete incoming mails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I have a bunch of filters that are designed to:

1. Label the mail into a particular label
2. Mark the email as read
3. Delete the email

The reason why I need to label some mails is that while I don't want these mails in my inbox (or Archive), I might need them in the short term (in less than 30 days). This might include order updates or OTPs. In these cases I can go to the trash and put another filter by label to search of such emails.

I've provided an example of such a filter below (screenshot). The problem: **the filter only applies the label and marks it as read. It does not delete the email, leaving it on my inbox!**

[image]

Comment: As it's currently written, this looks like a complaint that should / bug report should be addressed directly to Google. If you are looking for a workaround / alternative please improve the wording of your post to make it a better fit for this community. You should also show what you have tried to solve this problem by your own and show what relevant questions you have found and why they don't meet your needs.